# How can I bind WanaKana to a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, cjk, ime

Regarding the [WanaKana](https://github.com/WaniKani/WanaKana) javascript library, is it possible to bind it to a `<div contenteditable="true>`, instead of an `<input>` or a `<textarea>`, as the official documentation instructs? And if so, how can I achieve that?

I would like the users to be able to style the text they type (making it bold or italic, for instance), hence the need for a `<div contenteditable="true>`.

I already asked about this on GitHub, but I'm still waiting for a reply.

Comment: Just try it and find out? If it doesn't work, now you know, and if you absolutely need it, wanakana is on github: just file a feature request issue.

Comment: How are they going to make it bold or italic in content editable?

Comment: @TasosBu I have a button that calls the function: `document.execCommand("bold");`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for taking the time to reply. It didn't help me at all, regarding the problem I am facing, but at least it made me edit the question to make it clear that I am asking for a “how to” rather than a “is it possible”. I usually do try things out before asking if they are possible to achieve. Regarding my question, I cannot make it work. And I had already asked on GitHub before asking about it here.

Comment: Have tried using css to make the text bold or italic inside the input instead?

Comment: @TasosBu If I try something like this: `input { font-weight: bold; }`, it just styles the whole content of the `input`, which I do not want. I want the user to be able to apply some styling to, and only to, the text that is currently selected.

Comment: How about using a hidden input for the wanakana and use a div for the user?

Comment: @TasosBu I could probably come up with something like that, as a very last resort. But I would much rather have a clean solution, than having to deal with a workaround that is quite a hassle to code, to mantain, and to assure it works correctly across all major browsers.

Comment: I see you filed an issue on the github repo: nice! But please remember to put that in your post, too, so that people know to no longer recommend you do that.